# How should I describe this function mathematically regorously?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Suppose $f : [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and there exists $a\in [0,1]$ s.t.  $f(a)<0$.

Then, I want to show that there exists $g\in C^2([0,1])$ s.t.
\begin{align}
&g(a)=1\\
&0\leqq g(x)\leqq 1 \ \mathrm{\ for \ } x\in [0,1]\\
&g(x)=0 \mathrm{\ on \ } J^c \mathrm{\ where\ } J=\{ x\in [0,1]\mid f(x)<0 \}
\end{align}

($J^c$ is the complement of $J$.)

I sensorily understand that such $g$ exists by drawing picture, but I don't know how I should describe this $g$ or prove the existence of such $g$ **mathematically rigorously**. I think drawing picture is not rigorous argument.

(For example, I found that the bump function seems to work by drawing picture.)

I'd like you to give me the idea how I can show such $g$ exists.

Comment: Your post does not make clear: Do you already know (mathematically rigorously) that bump functions exist?

Comment: Such a function can be written in terms of a bump function. The level of rigor depends on what sort of bump function definition you consider rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of using bump functions should work.

Since $f$ is continuous, there is a maximal interval $[p,q]\subset[0,1]$ such that $a\in[p,q]$ and $f<0$ on $[p,q]$. If $a\in(0,1)$ then $b=\min\{|p-a|,|q-a|\}>0$, we can define $g$ as the bump function
\begin{align*}
&g(x)=\exp\left(1-\frac1{1-\left(x-a\right)^2/b^2}\right)\ \text{if}\ x\in[a-b,a+b]\\
&g(x)=0\ \text{otherwise}.
\end{align*}
You can easily check $g$ is smooth on $[0,1]$, $g(a)=1$ and $g(x)=0$ when $f(x)\geq0$.

If $a=0$, then $p=0$ and we can define $g$ by
\begin{align*}
&g(x)=\exp\left(1-\frac1{1-\left(x-a\right)^2/q^2}\right)\ \text{if}\ x\in[0,q]\\
&g(x)=0\ \text{otherwise}.
\end{align*}

Similarly for $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Since $f(a)<0$ and $f$ is continuous you can find an interval $I=(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)$ in which $f$ is negative. Now start with the $1D$ bump function
$$h(x) = \begin{cases}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right), \; x \in (-1, 1) \\ 0, \; \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). Can you figure a way to transform it in order to solve your problem (you'll need to move it and squeeze it appropriately)? Try playing with [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3dub6kzhp7) graph and I'm sure you'll figure it out.